# 4 linear equations, 5 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck on these linear equations and can't seem to find a way to express $x$, $y$, $z$ in terms of $a$, $b$. I'm not allowed to use the Gauss method.

\begin{align*}
4x + 3y + z &= 2a + b\\ 
x + 2y - z &= a\\ 
2x - y + 3z &= b\\
-x + 3y - 4z &= a - b 
\end{align*}

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried solving each equation in terms of 1 variable and substituting that in for the occurrence of that variable in the other equations? Example: $2x+y=3$ and $x+y=4$ then we can solve the first equation for $y$ and substitute this into the 2nd equation eliminating that $y$: $x+(3-2x)=4$

Comment: Gaussian elimination certainly looks like the appropriate tool for this problem. Do you have any idea (a textbook chapter title perhaps?) what method you _are_ supposed to use?

Comment: @Angelica I think I'm only allowed to use substitution/elimination and other trivial operations. This exercise is part of the chapter "linear combinations of vectors" (the equations were created from a vector equation) and technically we have not yet learned how to use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins I have tried to solve for x for example, but after plugging x in to the other 3 equations, I always end up with 0=0 for some reason

Comment: @CrazyBacon it helps to show this as part of your question. Let $t=$ some parameter to write the variable that "becomes $0$" in terms of. For example, if substitution forces your equation for $z$ to become $0$, let $z=t$ so that you can write the other equations in terms of this parameter. This is similar to when a row becomes all $0$'s while doing Guass elimination.

Comment: Since you have 4 equations in 3 variables, you're gonna have some dependancies. In particular, (4)=(2)-(3), so any of those three equations may be discarded as you solve for x,y,z. (But you still have to go back and check that your solution works for that unused equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designate the equations as $(1),(2),(3),(4)$.

Equation $(3) = (1) - 2*(2)$. So equation $(3)$ is useless.

Equation $(4) = 3*(2) - (1)$. So equation $(4)$ is useless.

By useless I mean it provides no new information.

There are only two linearly independent equations in five variables.